# Clash between verbatim and libertine

Tags: fonts, verbatim, libertine

I have a document with some `verbatim` in it and I wanted to change the font to libertine, but this also changes the verbatim parts. Is there a way to keep the `verbatim` parts in computer-y font while changing the text to libertine font?

```
\documentclass[25pt]{article} 
\usepackage{libertine, verbatim}

\begin{document} 
\verb|looks odd| 
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7):

It is not a clash! Package `libertine` defines all three font families roman (Libertine), sans serif (Biolinum), and mono (Libertine Mono).  Do not load the Libertine mono font if you do not want that:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article} 
\usepackage[mono=false]{libertine}
\usepackage{verbatim}

\begin{document} 
\verb|looks good| 
\end{document}
```

However, using Bera Mono as typewriter font looks better. It also has a bold variant:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[mono=false]{libertine}
\usepackage[scaled=0.85]{beramono}%% or 0.82
\usepackage{verbatim}
\begin{document} 
Normal text \textsf{Biolinum} \verb|looks good| \texttt{bera mono}

Also available in bold \textbf{\texttt{bera mono bold}} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I think "clash" has a technical meaning but I meant it in a colloquial sense. Anyway, this looks good. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
\documentclass[25pt]{article} 
\usepackage{libertine, verbatim}
    \makeatletter
    \g@addto@macro\verbatim\sffamily{}
    \makeatother
\begin{document} 
\verb|looks odd| 
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Adjust `\verbatim@font` to choose `cmtt` - the Computer Modern Typerwriter font that looks computer-y:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{libertine}
\begin{document}
looks good \verb|looks odd| looks good

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\verbatim@font}{\fontfamily{cmtt}\selectfont}
\makeatother

looks good \verb|looks odd| looks good
\end{document}
```